# Excel Interop RefreshAll method not working for remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, excel, wmi, excel-interop

I have two machines: Server & Client

**Server machine:** Created a Console .Net application that instantiates Excel Interop and calls RefreshAll method for a workbook.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyApp = new Excel.Application();
    MyApp.Visible = false;
    MyApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\RefreshSample.xlsm");
    Console.WriteLine("Giving refresh call..");

    MyBook.RefreshAll(); //refreshes pivots within workbook

    MyBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Copy1.xlsm");
    Console.WriteLine("Excel Refresh call finished");
    MyBook.Close();
    MyApp.Quit();

}
```

**Client machine:** Created a Console .Net application that uses WMI to call remote Server .Net Console application

```
public static void Main()
{
    ConnectionOptions options =  new ConnectionOptions();
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\remoteIP\\root\\cimv2", options);
    scope.Connect();
    // Get the object on which the 
    // method will be invoked
    ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
    ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
    ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass
        (scope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
    object[] methodArgs = { @"C:\RefreshExcelConnections.exe", null, null, 0 };
    //Execute the method 
    object result = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", methodArgs);
    //Display results
    Console.WriteLine("Creation of process returned: " + result);
    Console.WriteLine("Process id: " + methodArgs[3]);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Observations:**

- The Server console application runs properly when I run it in standalone mode by logging onto server and executing the EXE. It opens Excel application, refreshes Excel file properly and closes Excel application.
- The Client console application, when *.RefreshAll() is commented* in Server app, is able to create Excel application on remote Server machine, Save As.. and Close Excel application properly. I verified this by looking to task manager of Server machine and new file generated there.

**Problem:**

- The Client console application, when *.RefreshAll() is uncommented* in Server app, is able to create Excel application on remote Server machine. It seems to be stuck at this point. Even after waiting for so much time, the Refresh, Save As.. and closing of Excel application does not happen.

Both the client and server machines are in the same domain and I am running the client application under the same domain account that is also added to administrators group on server machine.

Any clue?

**Update:**
Using *PsExec*, I was able to open the server application in interactive mode. So client application using WMI is not used in this case. This is the command that I used on client machine to open server application in interactive mode.

```
psexec -i 0 \\RemoteServer C:\FolderPath\RefreshExcelConnections.exe
```

There is a popup that appears on remote server at which it gets stuck. The popup is titled "Multidimensional Connection 11.0" and it asks for Analysis Server Name and Credentials. I tried giving credentials in the popup but it is giving error "Open connection failed" without any specific error. I also checked that the data connection file (.ODC) is placed in C: and is accessible to user running the application. And it is this windows user that also has access to Cube server. So I am not sure why this connection error is poping up during remote call execution.

Comment: Make excel visible and try to see what actually happens. Maybe there is a dialog or connection problem...

Comment: I already made MyApp.Visible = true; however the remote server machine does not show it visibly. It however, runs in background and that is seen in task manager process list.

Comment: There is probably a way to make the process visible, maybe specifing some value in `methodArgs`... See `Win32_ProcessStartup`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx For security reasons the Win32_Process.Create method cannot be used to start an interactive process remotely.

Comment: Maybe you can check using WMI localy. Anyway, Excel is designed to run interactively. It's not adviced to run it on a server.